# Haskell type mismatch in do block

Tags: haskell, types, io, type-mismatch

While learning Haskell "for a greater good" (aka to pass the exams on functional languages),
I ran into a weird error. I get a Type mismatch error in every do-block (except the first one). To be more accurate, The compiler seems to expect a list of something.

I think it has something to do with the IO operations...

code:

```
-- chaos.hs
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do                                            -- no error
       inl <- openFile "dictionary.txt" ReadMode
       let lang = extractLang (inl)
       hClose inl

extractLang :: Handle -> String 
extractLang file = do                                --error
                   eof <- hIsEOF file
                   if eof
                      then do hClose file            --error
                              "none"
                      else do line <- hGetLine file  --error
                              if length (words line) == 1
                                then line
                                else extractLang file
```

the error log:

```
chaos.hs:12:27:
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
Expected type: [Bool]
  Actual type: IO Bool
In a stmt of a 'do' block: eof <- hIsEOF file
In the expression:
  do { eof <- hIsEOF file;
       if eof then
           do { hClose file;
                .... }
       else
           do { line <- hGetLine file;
                .... } }

chaos.hs:14:31:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
    Expected type: [()]
      Actual type: IO ()
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: hClose file
    In the expression:
      do { hClose file;
           "none" }

chaos.hs:16:39:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: IO String
        In a stmt of a 'do' block: line <- hGetLine file
        In the expression:
        do { line <- hGetLine file;
           if length (words line) == 1 then line else extractLang file
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are totally right in that it has to do with the IO operations. First, the proper type for `extractLang` is `Handle -> IO String`. Second, a couple of `return`s is missing (for the same reason):

```
extractLang :: Handle -> IO String
extractLang file = do                                
                   eof <- hIsEOF file
                   if eof
                      then do hClose file            
                              return "none"           -- return
                      else do line <- hGetLine file
                              if length (words line) == 1
                                then return line      -- return
                                else extractLang file
```